# Xcode: error when adding repository

Tags: xcode, svn, authentication, ssh, server

I want connect to myServer but it encounters an error. I've been searching on Google, but no answer.

What I did is:

1. Running Xcode
2. Creating a new project
3. Going to Preferences
4. Account > Add repository
5. Insert `svn+ssh://myID@myserver.org/~~~/`

This is the error message I get:

> Authentication failed because SSH could not connect to the repository "sample".

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

in terminal

ssh-keygen -R myServer